# JOptionPane with text wrapping using custom Swing component

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have written many projects using `JOptionPane`s, and almost every time I am frustrated by the fact that I cannot wrap text inside them.

I know `JOptionPane` supports HTML, but that always seems to fall short of doing what I want. For one thing, `JOptionPane` doesn't fully support HTML - the `max-width` property would be awesome to have, for example. For another, neither `<br />` nor `<p>` tags provide the functionality I'm really after - a JOptionPane that is small when the message is small, and can grow when the message is larger, but which does not get too large, and eventually breaks to a new line.

That brings me to my question. Is there some way to write a custom component of my own, maybe inheriting from a `JFrame` or something similar, which will allow me to simulate the effects of a `JOptionPane`, but which provides finer-grain control of the text displayed? This should include, at minimum, functionality to control max width and to wrap text.

I have not found an answer to this by searching other questions (maybe the answer is drowned out by all the answers saying "use HTML"). This is NOT a duplicate of those questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Exmaple]

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class OptionPaneUtilities {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OptionPaneUtilities.showMessage(null, "I sometimes I think we forget just how flexible the JOptionPane API is and what it can do. A little effort could go a long way");
    }

    public static void showMessage(Component comp, String message) {
        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(message, 1, 20);
        ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        ta.setLineWrap(true);
        ta.setOpaque(false);
        ta.setBorder(null);
        ta.setEditable(false);
        ta.setFocusable(false);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(comp, ta);
    }

}
```

Now, obviously, this is just a really simple example, you're going to have to spend some time thinking about how best to apply this concept to your own API so it meets your needs and provides you with the greatest amount of flexibility.

You could make use of a `JEditorPane` instead and get both plain text and HTML to work with out to much more effort

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about something such as just adding a line break so the option box doesn't show this long string of text? If so :

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This
                                     "\nmessage
                                     "\nhas
                                     "\nlinebreaks.")`

should suffice. Using \n(text) creates a line break. Hopefully this helps, have a good night. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that does not solve my issue. I want a component that is reusable and robust, and can generically handle any type of input I pass to it. I want to be able to pass it "Hi" or an entire paragraph and have it still display cleanly. I do NOT want to have to format every text I pass it manually by putting in a bunch of line breaks. In fact, the whole point of the question is to avoid doing something like this. There should be a component that does it for us.

Comment: @nhouser9 If I had a dollar for every time I heard someone say that.  The Swing API is very flexible, you'd be amazed what just a little bit of effort can produce. For example, did you know the `message` parameter to the `JOptionPane` is an `Object` and if you pass it a `Component` based object, it is simply "added" to the `JOptionPane`. Think on that for a few moments